# How to overclock multiple Nvidia GPUs in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, x-server

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
```

...worked for me! But I don't know why unless order matters.

However, even though a monitor, device and screen is laid out for devices 0, 1 and 2 within xorg.conf it only shows XScreens 0 and 1 within the Nvidia control panel.

I can't overclock my 9600 GT even though people say they can overclock theirs. And when I run "nvidia-settings -q [gpu:2]/GPUPerfModes" it says Perf:0 (the only level) is editable:

```
    Attribute 'GPUPerfModes' (boincseti2:0[gpu:2]): perf=0, nvclock=600,
  nvclockmin=600, nvclockmax=600, nvclockeditable=1, memclock=900,
  memclockmin=900, memclockmax=900, memclockeditable=1, memTransferRate=1800,
  memTransferRatemin=1800, memTransferRatemax=1800, memTransferRateeditable=1,
  processorclock=1500, processorclockmin=1500, processorclockmax=1500,
  processorclockeditable=1
xserver-settings
```

Even more strange is screen 0 is linked to my GT 420, Screen 1 should be linked to my GT 710, and screen 2 should be linked to my 9600 GT. But the 9600 shows a screen attached but the "Graphics Device" (My GT 710) does not but I can overclock the 710 and the 420.

[image: XServer settings]